# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Во время выполнения кода на python3.7.4.

```
def read(data: list[int]):
    pass


read([1,2,3,4])
```

Вылетает ошибка (на 3.10 все хорошо)

```
    def read(data: list[int]):
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Если заменить на

```
def read(data: list):
    pass


read([1,2,3,4])
```

Все работает.

Answer (score 3):

В более старом питоне будет выглядеть так:

```
from typing import List

def read(data: List[int]):
    pass

read([1,2,3,4])
```

А если с маленькой буквы написать `list[int]` старый питон не понимает, что вы от него хотите.

Answer (score 0):

я тоже получил такую ошибку, но в другом формате:

```
n = int(input())
list1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
sold1 = 1
sold2 = 2
minimal_rasn = abs(list1[0]-list[1])
for x in range(1, n-1):
    currentsold = x
    if abs(list1[currentsold - 1] - list1[currentsold - 2]) < minimal_rasn:
        sold1 = x + 1
        sold2 = x = 2
    minimal_rasn = abs(list1[currentsold - 1] - list1[currentsold - 2])
if abs(list1[0] - list1[n - 1]):
    sold1 = 1
    sold2 = n
print(format(sold1) + ' ' + format(sold1))
```

ничего, просто задачка на codeforces.com

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]